# Expected end of line but found identifier in Script Editor

Tags: applescript

I am trying to right click a button in the application "Pro Tools."

To do this I am trying to tell script editor/apple scripts to click the button using control down (which emulates a right click on a Mac). However, I keep getting an error message when I try to compile or run the code. I receive a syntax error message that says

> Expected end of line, etc. but found number.

or

> Expected end of line but found identifier.

that point to using.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Pro Tools"
        click button "Record Enable" of group "Normal Transport Buttons" of group "Transport View Cluster" of window "Edit: BB MASTER TEMPLATE 2019 v1-14 copy" using key code 59
    end tell
end tell
```

I have also tried using this code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    (click button "record enable" of group "normal transport buttons" of group "transport view cluster" of window "Edit: BB MASTER TEMPLATE 2019 v1-14 copy" of application process "Pro Tools")
    using key code 59
end tell
```

Comment: You cannot use e.g. `using key code 59` with a `click button` event!  **click** _v_ : cause the target process to behave as if the UI element were clicked & **click** [UI element] : The UI element to be clicked. So you can click the button, but you cannot also perform a key press at the same time.

Comment: Hi, Thanks you! Is there a work around for this? The end goal is just to have it act as if I right clicked this button. I can get it to click it regularly but I would like to right-click it. Is there a way to modify what I'm telling Script Editor to do in order to achieve this. I can get it to right click in Chrome just not in Pro Tools for some reason. Maybe it is specific to the application for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you'll make your life easier if you use nested tell blocks, like so:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Pro Tools"
        tell window "Edit: BB MASTER TEMPLATE 2019 v1-14 copy"
            tell group "Transport View Cluster"
                tell group "Normal Transport Buttons"
                    click button "Record Enable"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Takes up more space, yes, but it's much easier to debug.

That being said, you might try using the `perform` command instead of `click` or `key code`. I mean, if there is a key equivalent for right-clicking the button that would be easiest, just use:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Pro Tools"
        key code 59 using control down  *-- or whatever*
    end tell
end tell
```

but if not, try this first:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Pro Tools"
        tell window "Edit: BB MASTER TEMPLATE 2019 v1-14 copy"
            tell group "Transport View Cluster"
                tell group "Normal Transport Buttons"
                    tell button "Record Enable"
                        log properties
                        log actions
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

and if the log shows an action for the button that seems on-point you can invoke it directly using:

```
                tell group "Normal Transport Buttons"
                    tell button "Record Enable"
                        perform action 2 *-- or whatever*
                    end tell
                end tell
```

It's hard to say more without more information...